# Excel function to auto-populate current date based on adjacent cell variables

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am working on a spreadsheet to autofill current date based on variables in an adjacent cell. I figured out how to get the date to auto-populate if any data is entered into the adjacent cell, but I have six drop-down options in the cell in which I would like the date to populate in adjacent cell based on just four specific selections in this drop down. Then for the remaining two specific selections I would like the date to auto-populate in another column. It is proving a bit complex and thinking some VBA code may be required.

Currently I have this formula working to auto-populate current date when any data is entered in another designated cell column. =IF(AND(D2<>"",D2<>0),TODAY(),"")

This is working fine, but cannot get to work on just specific text entered in the cell and not just any text/data.
Thanks!
Jessica

Comment: If() with or() comes to mind.

Comment: @SolarMike where would you enter the specific text? Within here ()? One of the words in the drop down options is "in progress" and I'd like to get the date column to auto-populate on that specific selection. Another word in that same drop down is "complete" in which I'd like to get a column with completion date (current date) to auto-populate in that column.

Answer (score 1):

So have a look and expand as you need:

[image]

To save typing:

```
IF(AND(A2>=1000,OR(B2="Apples",B2="Bananas")),TODAY(),"error")
```

Dropdown has Apples, Bananas, Oranges, Pears.
And instead of matching the complete word you could do A* B* etc